# Prevent unmount in Strict Mode of React18

Tags: reactjs, typescript

According to [this](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/18#discussion-3385714),react behaves like the following with Strict Mode...

- React renders the component.
- React mounts the component

  - Layout effect setup code runs.
  - Effect setup code runs.
- React simulates the component being hidden or unmounted.

  - Layout effect cleanup code runs
  - Effect cleanup code runs
- React simulates the component being shown again or remounted.

  - Layout effect setup code runs
  - Effect setup code runs

However, I have a function like this...

```
  const [ac, setAC] = useState(new AbortController())

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => ac.abort();
  }, [ac]
```

This cleanup function is called every time when Strict Mode is enabled, but I wanna make it run as it behaves without Strict Mode (but I wanna keep Strict Mode).

Are there any good ways to do it?

I tried something like that

```
// Use a Ref to hold the value, but initialize it in an effect.
const ref = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  // Initialize an imperative API inside of the same effect that destroys it.
  // This way it will be recreated if the component gets remounted.
  const someImperativeThing = ref.current = new SomeImperativeThing();

  return () => {
    someImperativeThing.destroy();
  };
}, []);

const handeThing = (event) => {
  const someImperativeThing = ref.current;
  // Now we can call methods on the imperative API...
};
```

But it doesnt work as I expected...